# Cut lines of /etc/passwd of users of the same group

Tags: linux, awk, grep, cut, passwd

I want to cut the lines of `/etc/passwd` of users of the same group.

If my group have the uid 1009 I want all the lines of `/etc/passwd` of this group

```
user1:x:1001:1009::/home/user1:/bin/bash
user2:x:1002:1009::/home/user2:/bin/bash
user3:x:1003:1009::/home/user3:/bin/bash
```

I tried `cat /etc/passwd | grep 1009` but it doesn't work because the number 1009 can be also a uid or other number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `awk` to compare the forth field against the uid you want using the field separator `:`

```
$ awk -F: '$4==1009' /etc/passwd
user1:x:1001:1009::/home/user1:/bin/bash
user2:x:1002:1009::/home/user2:/bin/bash
user3:x:1003:1009::/home/user3:/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat /etc/passwd | egrep '([^:]+:){3}1009:'
```

"Three lots of (some not-colons then a colon), followed by 1009 then another colon."

(You need the trailing colon to omit group 10090.)

Comment: Why are you concatenating (`cat`) the input file with nothing and then piping the result to grep instead of just having grep work directly on the file?

Comment: Indeed looks like an [UUOC](https://www.google.fr/search?q=uuoc) ^^  (But there could be "readability" reasons: best reason I read so far was someone pointing out it allow to read the command following the flow of information, instead of having the source (here, the file) at the end of the first command...) (and that's probably this reason that is the source of so many UUOC's out there. I do it too, sometimes, as when not thinking about efficiency it seems more "natural", even though it creates subprocesses and pipes and buffering...)

Comment: @EdMorton: Just because that's how the OP expressed his question.  But now that I think about it, I agree with Olivier.

Comment: @OlivierDulac If you just want to specify the file name on the left side of the command instead of the right you can do `</etc/passwd egrep '([^:]+:){3}1009:'`, still no need for a separate command and pipe. Personally I still wouldn't as it feels unnatural but maybe I've just gotten used to having the command first. Hey, I just realised your argument doesn't make sense as you STILL have the command first but now the command is `cat` instead of `egrep`!

Comment: well, good points. Anyway, one of the [UUOC](https://www.google.fr/search?q=uuoc) results links to unix.org posts saying that in **some** cases the cat ... | cmd is faster (usually when "cmd" is less efficient readnig the data from a file than "cat" is)... but in general, I avoid UUOC's anyway (less overhead) ^^

Comment: For that to be true "cmd" would have to be less efficient reading data from a file than the combination of "cmd" reading from a pipe PLUS "cat" reading from a file. I can't imagine that ever being the case so I think whatever link you're referring to is describing an urban legend.